# Gensim Word2Vec: poor training performance.

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, text-mining, gensim, word2vec

that might actually be a dumb question but I just can't figure out why my script with gensim.models.word2vec is not working. Here is the thing, I'm using the stanford sentiment analysis databank dataset (~11000 reviews), and i'm trying to build word2vec using gensim, this is my script:

```
import gensim as gs 
import sys 

# open the datas
sentences = gs.models.word2vec.LineSentence('../processedWords.txt')
print("size in RAM of the sentences: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(sentences)))

# transform them
# bigram_transformer = gs.models.Phrases(sentences)

model = gs.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=10, size=100, window=5)
model.save('firstModel')
print(model.similarity('film', 'test'))
print(model.similarity('film', 'movie'))
```

Now, my problem is that the script runs in 2s, and gives only huge similarity between every pair of words. In addition, some words which are in the sentences are not in the built vocabulary.

I must be doing something obviously wrong, but can't figure what.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the `processedWords.txt` file contains what you think it does?
 If you enable logging, what does it show? The dataset is small enough to fit in memory; what happens if you convert it into a list (`sentences = list(sentences)`) and check its length (`len(sentences)`)?

Comment: Yeah it shows 10605, which is basically what i expected, but I just think that my dataset is too small for word2vec, i tried with a much bigger dataset and it seems to gives better results

Comment: I see, that is a very small number of training-contexts for inducing good word vectors. With small datasets, a smaller model (reduced vector `size`) and increased number of iterations (say `iter=50` or more) can sometimes eke out better results, but more data is always preferable.

Comment: In addition i've been using cbow instead of skip-gram, I don't know if this can make a big difference. According to Mikolov, sg performs better, but at this point i don't know if that's crucial. Anyway, i'll try with reduced size and increased iter and will give a review here, thanks !

Comment: The skip-gram vs CBOW differences are usually fairly subtle – I've not seen a dataset where one gives usable results, and the other not. (Instead, it's a matter of incrementally optimized performance, or a little faster training.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm almost certain that this is because you haven't specified a number of training iterations; I think `iter` defaults to 1, which is basically useless for training a neural net. Add the `iter=<int>` flag to your model declaration, e.g. `model = gs.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=10, size=100, window=5, iter=1000)`.
Kind of a face-palmer but I did the same exact thing.